# Error building package cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins in tum_simulator

Tags: quadcopter, uav, rosmake, parrot, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi all,**

**I am trying to install the tum_simulator package following the instruction shown on the ROS wiki page. When I get to building the cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins package (using rosmake) I am getting the following error:**

[ 30%] [ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o

Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.dir/src/quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp.o

/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:38:29: fatal error: physics/physics.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp:45:29: fatal error: physics/physics.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/build'

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all] Error 2

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.dir/src/quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp.o] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/build'

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.dir/all] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/build'

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/build'

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins written to:

[ rosmake ]    /home/jp/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130718-150515/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/build_output.log

[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins [FAIL] [ 5.36 seconds ]

[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins.

[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.

[ rosmake ] Results:

[ rosmake ] Built 53 packages with 1 failures.

[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory

[ rosmake ] /home/jp/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130718-150515

**Could someone kindly point out what is causing the problem? From what I can understand the "physics.h" header file in "diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp" does not exist. If that is the case how could I solve it?**

**Thanks in advance,**
**JP**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67656/error-building-package-cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins-in-tum_simulator/) by [jpcallus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5272/jpcallus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is not an answer to your problem but I found several problems installing the tum_simulator using groovy. I tried to find a way to fix these issues but had no luck. As a result I installed ubuntu 12.04 and ros Fuerte and everything worked perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) with karma: 182 on 2013-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1